# IIS Web Farm Sticky Sessions based on Source IP or Custom Headers

Tags: iis, load-balancing

I am trying to build IIS Web farming for load balancing. I have set the Client Affinity to true but even after setting this, my requests are not stick to the same node. I want to to set the sticky sessions based on IP addresses. For example, if a request come from 1.2.3.4 then it should go to node 1 and 1.2.3.5 should go to node 2 and in the same manner new client IPs should get nodes in round robin fasion.

Please suggest if you have done this or if could give me good documentation of IIS web farming sticky sesions.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use iis URL rewrite rule to implement your requirement.

1. Use condition in web farm rule REMOTE_ADDR or SERVER_ADDR (based on your requirement) redirect to the specific farm.
2. The other option is to have your load balancer pass along a different HTTP header.  URL Rewrite can have a condition based on any header.